# how to use AWS Eventbridge Schema Registry code binding typescript Marshaller?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, schema, confluent-schema-registry, aws-event-bridge

I am new to eventbridge schema registry and typescript. After I set a registry and schema in aws console, and download the code bindings. I am wondering how to use this `Marshaller` class? I know checking schema basically is to encode and decode data, and see types are correct or not. But I did not get how to use the `Marshaller` 's `marshall` and `unmarshal` method. Especially `marshall(data: any, type: string)` how to pass in the type parameter.